# IMEI Number status is unknown AUXUS NOTE 5.5

Tags: imei

I have changed my SIM from my another Android phone (which was Lava X1) to Auxus Note 5.5. As soon as I changed and rebooted phone, it got locked.

I understood that it was due to Mobile antitheft apps was been install in the Lava X1.

Now I restored Firmware with help of service support but its IMEI number has been lost and I am not able to restore it.  Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to my experiences,

you just need the `Region Rom` for your `Operator and Country` and flash the Modem in your phone.and of course, if you have any backup of `Efs`, just restore or flash it.

also, try to download stock rom for your region and then test it.

hope this fixed. else,

maybe you need the `BoX` for fix this.